# Machine learning. The i.i.d assumption (help me with notation)

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning

Can someone explain what the author meant in the underlined sentence that $D^{m}$ should be. And it would be great if the answer being with the mathematical notation so that the meaning is unambiguous.

The book is **Understanding Machine Learning:
From Theory to Algorithms
by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David**

Page 38.
[image]

Comment: Let the sample $S=\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$ have size $m$. Each $x_i$ is drawn i.i.d. according to $\mathcal{D}$. You can think of $S \sim \mathcal{D}^m$ as a shorthand for this concept. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_independent_variables) for why we write this as a product $\mathcal{D}^m = \mathcal{D} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{D}$.